# Contrast issue in text and background color on GTK-style menus

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk, qt

The text color and background color of (I believe) GTK-themed QT applications' menus is matching, making the text hard to read. What normally happens is that when the background is dark, the text is light and viceversa, but with several GTK themes it's not. Note that it's *not* only when the button is disabled.

What is causing this and how can it be fixed?

What I've tried:

- changing GTK theme from Gnome tweaks (Ambiance works fine, but nothing else does)
- changing QT theme in qt5ct

Ubuntu 18.04, gnome-shell 3.28.2

[image: screenshot]